# delphi 7 paradox database records gone after closing delphi

Tags: delphi-7

i am currently learning to use a paradox database in delphi 7 and everything goes well except for the records. The records are there when i restart the program but if close delphi they will be gone. I am missing something?

Testing with a simple table that has only a auto increment field.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin

Table1.DatabaseName := 'STANDARD1';
Table1.TableName := 'TEST.DB';
DataSource1.DataSet := Table1;
dbGrid.DataSource := DataSource1;
Table1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Table1.Append ; // 
Table1.Post;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Table1.Close;
end;
```

Comment: Show your code, it's important to see what are you doing.

Comment: sounds like your program is not reading from the database. But there is no way to tell without seeing any code

Comment: What is the CashedUpdates property value of your Table1?

Comment: The CrashedUpdates property value is False